# carrierwave-aws and image_tag not working together well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, carrierwave, amazon-cloudfront

I am only starting here because the issue cropped up after I switched from fog to carrierwave-aws.  My image tags are rendering like this:

```
<%= image_tag(current_user.avatar.thumb.url, class: "img-circle") %>    
<img class="img-circle" src="https://xxxx.cloudfront.net/images/xxx.cloudfront.net/user/9/avatar_thumb.png" alt="Avatar thumb">
```

but `current_user.avatar.thumb.url` outputs `https://xxxx.cloudfront.net/user/9/avatar_thumb.png`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh!

```
config.asset_host = "https://xxxx.cloudfront.net"
```

not:

```
config.asset_host = "xxxx.cloudfront.net"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think should below code:

```
<%= image_tag current_user.avatar_url, :class=> 'img-circle' %>
```

I don't no why you use `thumb`.

`avatar` your DB column name

Hope will help you

Comment: Thumb is the image version